# Prove that all eigenvalues have negative real parts of a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $a,b,c,d>0$ and $s=a+b+c+d$. Consider the matrix:

$$A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1-s & a & b & c & 0 & d \\
        a & -s & b & c & d & 0 \\
        b & c & -s & d & 0 & a \\
        c & d & 0 & -s & a & b \\
        d & 0 & a & b & -s & c \\
        0 & a & b & c & d & -s-1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

We need to show that all eigenvalues of $A$ have negative real parts.
My idea is to use Gershgorin circle theorem. But the trouble is I could not rule out the case when $A$ has eigenvalue to be $0$. Could anyone give some suggestions?

Comment: That is a real matrix, so if what you say is true it must have only real eigenvalues

Comment: I don't think so, because real matrix could have complex eigenvalues, for example, A=[0,1;0,0] has two complex eigenvalues.

Comment: Oh yeah, I thought the imaginary part was negative.